# PEAR Mail - Failed to connect

Tags: php, email, pear

This has been taunting me for 3 days straight now. I have pear installed and the script is fine as I've used it in many other projects. My question being what reasons would I get

```
Failed to connect to mail.domain.co.uk:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection timed out (code: -1, response: )]
```

I've tried several different accounts and gmail accounts which the code I used was from stackoverflow which had 50+ votes so must work! Is there any serverside restrictions that maybe in place? My code is at follows.

```
<?php
require_once "/usr/local/lib/php/Mail.php";

$from = "<notifications@domain.co.uk>";
$to = "<doe@domain.co.uk>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$host = "mail.domain.co.uk";
$username = "notifications.domain.co.uk";
$password = "fu*****";

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

any help would be very greatfull

Comment: Can you telnet to that host's port 25 independently of PHP? If you can't even telnet, then something's blocking your connection attempts (firewall?) rather than it being a bug in your PHP code.

Answer (score 3):

I reckon it has nothing to do with PEARMail. Try doing `telnet mail.domain.co.uk 25` from the machine where PHP is executing. If you get a timeout as well, it's not PEARMail, it's networking. It can be any number of reasons: firewalls, routing, some links inbetween etc.

Basically the stage of sending mail which fails for you is establishing a TCP connection to the mailserver on port 25. Debug that first and when you can establish a `telnet` connection - I'm fairly certain your PHP will work too.

--- edit ---

One more thing came to my mind. Should you be by any chance running this on your local home box, connected to your standard household DSL operator, many of them block outgoing port 25. In that case, they make use of a so-called `smarthost`, basically an SMTP relay on their own premises, which will accept any mail from you to any address. Look for it on your ISP's webpages, they must make it known and then use it instead of mail.domain.co.uk.

--- edit2 ---

Let's rule out PEARMail then.

Try the following smallish piece of code as a separate script:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("mail.domain.co.uk", 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "I'm connected!<br />\n";
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

This should rule out PEARMail as this is a drop-dead simple poor man telnet replacement.

Comment: This isn't my hosting, I'm subing for a small company who uses another company for hosting with cpanel and such but dont think I have command line access. Thanks a lot though, will probe further

Comment: @PhilJackson: I edited my post with a simple connection tester. If this gives you a time-out as well, you at least can for now rule out PEARMail.

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to mail.domain.co.uk:25 (Connection timed out) in /home/usr/public_html/path/file.php on line number
Connection timed out (110)

Comment: Sorry, have on-call shift and had an incident. Yeah, so you see it has nothing to do with PEARMail :)